# How to terminate an activity and switch to another one?

Tags: java, android

I'm doing something like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    User user = new Entrance().enter();
    // continue with user, since it's a valid one
  }
}
// I'm using this class from many activities
public class Entrance {
  public User enter() {
    try {
      User user = new Hub().enter();
    } catch (AuthenticationFailedException ex) {
      this.startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
      this.finish();
    }
    return user;
  } 
}
```

This code doesn't work because `finish()` doesn't throw an exception and let the execution flow continue. What is the proper design for this scenario?

Comment: try "noHistory" for MyActivity in manifest.

Comment: return null, or throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Activity.isFinishing()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing()) method to seperate your flow of logic.

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    User user = new Entrance().enter();
    // continue with user, since it's a valid one
    if (isFinishing()) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the Entrance class from multiple Activities, you should pass the Context of the Activity to the enter() method in the Entrance class. It should be as follows:

```
public User enter(Context context) {
  try {
    User user = new Hub().enter();
  } catch (AuthenticationFailedException ex) {
    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class));
    context.finish();
  }
  return user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, first create an intent ,2nd finish the activity start next/desired activity through intent

```
Intent loginIntent=new Intent(MyActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
MyActivity.this.finish();
startActivity(loginIntent);
```